# Can caster prove truthfulness with "Zone of Truth"

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I've seen a lot of posts about how "Zone of Truth" might be defeated by the target.  But my character has the opposite problem: he's extremely truthful but people don't always believe him.  Is there any mechanism for using Zone of Truth to make verifiably True statements?

If I cast ZoT, I know (to first order) who in the zone succeeds or fails.  I would also have to make a save, which I could fail voluntarily. Is there any way I could reliably convince my interlocutors that I did indeed fail (note: this isn't "convince them I'm telling the truth when I'm lying" but "convince them I'm telling the truth when I am."

The benefit of this is illustrated by [a binding oath](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Three_Oaths) taken some of the magic users of the [Wheel of Time fantasy series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time):

> One of the great powers of the Aes Sedai First Oath was that if an Aes Sedai made a statement without evasion, then all knew it to be true and reliable.  And if the Aes Sedai said "I am not trying to mislead you, you understand my point correctly" it was more powerful.

Zone of Truth has precisely the opposite power.

Comment: I'm confused by the inclusion of the 'Aes Sedai First Oath' component of the question. Could that be removed and still preserve what I think is your initial question, "How can a character use Zone of Truth to demonstrate they are being truthful?"

Comment: Are you certain that you can fail the saving throw voluntarily? That portion is the only one which makes me think the game might not be D&D 5e. The Wheel of Time reference seems only to be an analogy illustrating what the OP hopes to achieve with the proposed usage of Zone of Truth.

Comment: So essentially the problem is the reverse of what ZoT provides: instead of you knowing whether everyone else is lying, you want everyone else to know whether *you* are lying?

Comment: @Upper_Case 5e doesn't have rules allowing for deliberately failing saving throws, but IME it's a common house rule (either because it makes sense that you could choose not to resist an effect or just because there were rules for this in previous editions). You probably shouldn't put too much importance on that bit.

Comment: Related on [Can you choose to fail a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47487/can-you-choose-to-fail-a-saving-throw)

Comment: I think your best bet is finding someone *else* who can cast *ZoT* and have them vouch for you.

Answer (score 12):

#### No.

This is pretty straightforward. The only person who necessarily gains knowledge on whether or not a creature within the radius of *Zone of Truth* has been affected by the spell, and therefore is or is not capable of lying, is the caster.

Since the character in question is not considered reliably honest by the others (that's why there's a question of honesty in the first place), the character's own word about whether or not they are affected by the spell is similarly unreliable. If that would work, they might as well not bother with *Zone of Truth* at all.

This is particularly true if you are hoping for others' views of this character to include a reputation similar to *inability* to lie. Aes Sedai *cannot* lie, with magical effects physically preventing them from directly expressing, verbally or in writing, something that they believe is untrue. Trying to use *Zone of Truth* in that way may even backfire-- without the spell being in effect, people may assume that the character is lying simply because they are eliding the situation in which lying would be impossible to get away with.

The correct solution involving RAW *Zone of Truth* would be for the character to submit to *another* character casting the spell, perhaps repeatedly until the character fails the saving throw (voluntarily or otherwise). If your character is really focused on this, building them to be able to produce spell scrolls for *Zone of Truth* and then giving those scrolls to others so that the spell is as available as possible to other people might be the closest RAW solution involving this spell.

Other options in this area will certainly exist as well, but lie outside of the scope of this question. As quick examples, someone could cast *Wish* on a character to produce this effect, homebrew spells/curses/feats/magic items can impose it, and so on.

---

**Experience Note:**

I've run NPCs with inability to lie as a trait, and found mechanics surrounding that to be unimportant (players don't trust them, much like Aes Sedai are not much trusted because they can be misleading without lying). The hard part is actually making sure they never lie, because the players/DM at the table have no constraints on lying whether a character does or not.

Comment: It probably isn't necessary to cast *zone of truth* repeatedly - by the RAW, a creature in the zone must [save repeatedly until it eventually fails](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99740/28402). You'd have to be extremely lucky to resist the spell for the entire ten-minute duration.

Comment: Yeah, the reputational problems are ones I'm worried about. That's part of why I'm looking for a method in which I could say "the information written on this piece of paper is 100% correct to the best of my knowledge, without an attempt to evade or mislead" and have that one particular statement be believed.  Obviously they will still suspect ulterior motives, but it could potentially be useful in situations such as "my party has done something kind of bonkers and nobody believes us or our warnings".

Comment: The Glibness spell prevents lie detection via spell.

Comment: @ScottDunnington as explored a bit in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147310/28402), *glibness* and similar effects which confound "magic that would determine if you are telling the truth" don't necessarily interact with a *zone of truth* at all. (*Zone of truth* doesn't detect whether you are lying, it just enchants you so that it is impossible for you to lie; truth is *inferred* from the knowledge that you have been successfully enchanted.)

Comment: > If your character is really focused on this, building them to be able to produce spell scrolls for Zone of Truth and then giving those scrolls to others so that the spell is as available as possible to other people might be the closest RAW solution involving this spell

Is there a RAW way to be sure that a given scroll actually does what the provider claims that it does? In particular, [it might be cursed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68313/can-a-character-detect-that-an-item-is-cursed)?

Comment: @scubbo I guess you could bootstrap it? Make the scrolls, then get some trustworthy NPC to cast Zone of Truth, then say "these scrolls are uncursed Zone of Truth scrolls" from inside it. From then on, you can always use your last verified scroll to verify a bunch of new scrolls, so you don't need to keep going back to the NPC.

Answer (score 8):

## Statistically, Yes

There is no game mechanic or loophole in the spell that would allow your interrogator to determine that you have failed your save. However, the spell lasts for 10 minutes and requires you to repeat the save every turn you enter or stay in the spell's radius. Therefore, the following strategy is perfectly viable:

1. Cast the spell
2. Enter the spell's area
3. Repeat the same (true) statement every round, 100 times, until the spell expires

100 repetitions of the saving throw gives you about a 99.5% chance to fail at least once even if you have a 95% chance of success each time. This should be enough to persuade a skeptical interrogator. If not, simply repeat the process.

Of course, this technique requires your interrogator to understand how the spell works and to have a decent understanding of probability. Depending on the type of world your game takes place in and the type of person interrogating you, this may or may not be reasonable to hope for. As a DM, I might allow this trick to work against an intelligent NPC wizard who has studied this particular spell, but probably not anyone else. In the fiction, I would rule that such an NPC has a general understanding of the near-impossible difficulty of resisting the spell for the entire duration, rather than having them calculate the precise probability based on meta-concepts like your saving throw bonus.

As pointed out in a comment by @carcer, if your interrogator doubts that you have actually cast the spell at all, they can simply step into the area with you and experience its effects for themselves. Again, this may only be persuasive to someone who has studied this particular spell themselves.

Comment: @NautArch You do, in fact, repeat the save each turn: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99740/how-many-saves-do-you-roll-vs-zone-of-truth

Comment: I totally didn't read it that way! Learned something new :)

Comment: @Joe you also need a way to convince the interrogator that you have, in fact, cast the spell and are maintaining the spell... which should be doable if they're also in the area with you, since they'll also most likely fail a save quickly and thereafter know the spell is up for as long as they can't lie.

Comment: @Upper_Case I don't think the NPC needs to understand the mechanics of saving throws, necessarily. If a player tried this in my game, I would rule that a sufficiently learned or experienced caster would understand that anyone under the influence of this spell is constantly fighting the compulsion to tell the truth, and to resist this compulsion for the entire duration would require a nearly impossible reserve of willpower. I do agree it requires fairly niche circumstances to work, as I say in my last paragraph.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, bad timing! I wanted to reword my comment. The core piece of it is that the knowledge of dice rolling mechanics for saving throws is necessary for the statistical precision described here, which seems to me to be the core of this strategy. A line or two about that in the answer will improve it, as the abstracted game mechanics are unevenly assumed to be known by in-universe characters. Repeating this strategy *ad infinitum* can address the uncertainty from not knowing the mechanics, but is maybe not so practical.

Comment: @Upper_Case good advice, I've added a line on handling this in fiction

Comment: The problem then lies with characters like sorcerers who have Careful Spell, right? If you were, say, Cleric/Sorcerer, you could cast Zone of Truth and have your colleague enter the zone. The interlocutor does the same and experiences the effect. But you've cast it Carefully, so your colleague is *not* affected by it. I think the only way I'd be truly (mostly) confident is to have my own trusted caster running the spell.  And even then, there are some risks from things like Modify Memory or Dominate Person.  Any sufficiently high-level negotiations will have countermeasures for that, though.

Answer (score 7):

### By itself, *zone of truth* can't prove your own honesty

The spell only does what it says it does, and though you could affect yourself with your own *zone of truth* and therefore be forced to be truthful, there is no mechanism in the spell which grants the knowledge you have about whether or not any subject is affected by the spell to anyone else.

However, if you have a way to give your interlocutor the ability to cast *zone of truth*, then you have reversed the situation and can invite them to subject you to the effect to prove your honesty. The easiest way I can think of to do this off the top of my head would be to lend your interlocutor a *[ring of spell storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing)* into which you have cast *zone of truth* already, so they can attune to it and then cast it on you. Any creature can use the *ring of spell storing* (unlike a scroll of the same) so it doesn't require the interlocutor to be a capable caster themselves, but it does require you to have an hour available so they can attune to the item (and, ideally, another hour so you can attune to it again after they give it back).

If you're in the specific case of dealing with an individual who is a spellcaster with the spell *[identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify)* prepared, you could subject yourself to a *zone of truth* and then invite them to cast *identify* on you, because:

> If you instead touch a creature throughout the casting, you learn what spells, if any, are currently affecting it.

Thus, they can verify with their own magic that you are in fact affected by a *zone of truth*. If they're also inside the *zone of truth*, it would be obvious to them if the spell ends, as they will suddenly be able to lie.

Comment: I like this solution, even if it's still difficult.  It's still pretty difficult, and requires a trusted interlocutor capable of casting Identify (which is itself an expensive spell, with the 100 GP pearl).  However, it does provide a method of verifying the truthfulness of two separate parties.

Comment: One other option could be to have overlapping Zone of Truth spells, with one caster on each side of the discussion.  Then each side would be able to strongly accept that (a) both casters are bound by truth spell, and (b) which other parties are bound by it, since you already have (a).

Comment: @Necarion I feel like we're getting dangerously close to accidentally inventing high fantasy magical key exchange algorithms...

Comment: What would a Private Key look like?  I'm also amused that someone named @Carcer is giving me advice on how to be honest in a fantasy setting.

Comment: @Carcer You say that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: @Necarion just don't ask me how many knives I'm carrying.

Comment: Well, when it comes time to empty them all on the table, there will be one more that you "forgot" and give me with a sheepish expression.  As is the thematic requirement in such situations.

Comment: Does Zone of Truth even require concentration? From the question I've read so far, I was under the impression it doesn't.

Comment: @EgorHans oh, you're right. No way to end it early besides actively dispelling it (or some other anti-magic effect).

Comment: this sounds like an awesome solution in a high magic setting for negotiations between nations. Each nation has someone who is in charge of casting the zone of truth from a ring, preferably someone that nation trusts. Maybe even have someone use zone of truth to vet that person before hand. That would make infiltration of diplomatic functions more difficult, the more people you involve the better (they can't all be spies). Once your chosen person is vetted and you know they are not a spy then they cast zone of truth at the delegation. The other side does the same and then you have negotiations.

Comment: @Necarion: Identify doesn't consume the pearl; it requires an investment in that component but has no per-cast cost other than time (assuming you cast as a ritual without a spell slot, thus 11 minutes).